# How to get sum of each type

Tags: laravel

I have a `collection` and would like to sum by `type`.

```
[
  ['type' => 0, 'amount' => 5],
  ['type' => 1, 'amount' => 5],
  ['type' => 0, 'amount' => 5]
]
```

What I want:

```
[
  ['type' => 0, 'amount' => 10],
  ['type' => 1, 'amount' => 5]
]
```

How can I achieve this in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 $yourCollectionSums = $yourCollection->groupBy('type')
   ->map(function ($row) {
     return $row->sum('amount');
   });
 
 $result = [];

 foreach($yourCollectionSums as $key => $sum){
    $result[$key] = ['type' => $key, 'sum' => $sum]
 }

 // $result will give you desired result.
```

Comment: Thank you, this returns an array of sums, how can I keep the format like `['type' => X, 'amount' => SUMX]` ?

Comment: the key is type id and value is sum, not just array of sums

Comment: So this won't work when type 0 is not given, right?

Comment: Yeah because there is no type:0 inside your collection. If you want to do it then you should iterate overyour loop.

Comment: I changed the answer to show type etc. Please do not forget to mark is an answer if it is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

try the code will help you

```
$result[] = [];
    $collection = $collection->groupBy('type')
                             ->map(function ($row) {
                                 return $row->sum('amount');
                             })
                             ->map(function ($amount, $type) {
                                 $result['type'] = $type;
                                 $result['amount'] = $amount;

                                 return $result;
                             });
```

Comment: Also thanks to you, this is also working as expected.